# Clojure add var to namespace

Tags: clojure, namespaces

How can I add a var to a clojure namespace, i.e. so it can be retrieved later through a call to ns-interns?

This is **not** (intern ns sym ...), because intern creates a var or reuses whatever var sym is bound to. This distinction is important when other namespaces require ns and hold references to the vars in ns. What I am asking for is the opposite of ns-unmap.

Comment: Are you saying you want to add an existing var to a different namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `def`?:

```
def
Creates and interns or locates a global var with the name of symbol and a
namespace of the value of the current namespace (*ns*).
```

and in code:

```
(def alpha)
(def beta :boo)
(intern 'tst.demo.core 'gamma :charlie)

(ns-interns 'tst.demo.core)
    => {alpha  #'tst.demo.core/alpha,  
        beta   #'tst.demo.core/beta
        gamma  #'tst.demo.core/gamma}
```

I'm not sure what you're after here...? They all seem the same.

Comment: "CREATES and inters a var". I want to add my-var to the namespace, so that alter-var-root (my-var ...) changes the value of the symbol I choose.

Answer (score 0):

#### Background: `ns-interns` vs `ns-map`

`ns-interns` returns a map of Vars originally interned in the given namespace. There's no way to take a Var from one namespace and make it show up in another namespace's output of `ns-interns`. Thus if you want to make a Var show up here, you'll need to use `intern` or `def`.

In contrast, `ns-map` is the more fundamental primitive that returns a potentially larger map that includes "own interns", but also Vars from other namespaces brought in through `:require :refer` and imported Java classes.

(It is more fundamental because `ns-interns` works by calling `ns-map` and filtering it so that only Vars originally interned in the given namespace are kept. This is possible because Vars keep track of the namespace they where created in, if any, and any originally assigned name.<sup>1</sup>)

The map that `ns-map` returns is the one that `ns-unmap` removes mappings from. Note that `ns-map` and `ns-unmap` make no distinction between "own Vars" and Vars from other namespaces. Var entries in this map are created when you use `intern` or `def`, but also when Vars from other namespaces are mapped in. If the latter is what you want to do, there are several ways to go about it.

#### Adding Vars from other namespaces to a given namespace's `ns-map`

The standard way is to use `:require :refer … :rename …` or `:use :only … :rename …`  in the `ns` form or `clojure.core/refer :only … :rename …` at the REPL:

```
user=> (refer 'clojure.string :only '[lower-case] :rename '{lower-case lc})
nil
user=> (lc "ASDF")
"asdf"
```

NB. the argument following `:only` is a collection of non-namespaced symbols that name the Vars you want to pull in in their own namespace – the original names – and the `:rename` map has the original names in the key position and your replacement names in the value position.

If you're happy to accept the original name, you can leave out `:rename`.

It's also possible to call `clojure.core/require` or `clojure.core/use`, which will ensure that the namespace is loaded and then `refer` the Vars you need. The syntax is as in an `ns` form – see below – except the collections of symbols following `:only` and `:rename` need to be quoted as in the `refer` call above.

In an `ns` form you'd say

```
(:require [clojure.string :refer [lower-case] :rename {lower-case lc}])
```

or

```
(:use [clojure.string :only [lower-case] :rename {lower-case lc}])
```

`:require` tends to be preferred these days as a matter of style.

---

<sup>1</sup> For completeness, it is possible to create Vars that don't consider themselves to belong to any namespace or to have any particular name, but there's no public API for adding those to any namespace map as of right now; in fact their presence in a namespace map would cause certain weird behaviours.